# XML / PHP / Variable

Tags: php, xml

I'm using the following XML file:

http://xml.nordicbet.com/football.xml

```
    $xml = simplexml_load_file('http://xml.nordicbet.com/football.xml');

    foreach ($xml as $gameinfo):
    $kodate=$gameinfo->GameStartTime;
    $status=$gameinfo->Status;
    $id=$gameinfo->EventID;
    $league=$gameinfo->LeagueID;
    $hometeam=$gameinfo->Participant[0];
    $awayteam=$gameinfo->Participant[1];
    $region=$gameinfo->Region;
    $sport=$gameinfo->Sport;
    $season=$gameinfo->Season;
    $livebet=$gameinfo->LiveBet;
```

These variables are working correctly, but as you see in the code, there are a lot of OutcomeSet tags, how do I go about getting the information where

```
    <OutcomeSet type="Result" id="50001643467" name="FC Seoul - Ulsan Hyundai Horang-I">
    <Outcome odds="1.75" id="50069765963" name="1">
    <Participant info="Football" id="10000020100">FC Seoul</Participant></Outcome>
    <Outcome odds="3.4" id="50069765964" name="X"/>
    <Outcome odds="4.05" id="50069765965" name="2">
```

In the above code, I'm wanting to extract the 3 'odds' - so 1.75, 3.4 and 4.05 - as seperate variables which I could use in the same was as my other variables

It's the information out of any OutcomeSet tag where the type is 'Result' that I'm after

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

within the foreach u can call getName method on $gameinfo variable, it will return the name of the current XML element

this code prints out the odds values

```
foreach ($xml as $gameinfo) {
    if ("Outcome" == $gameinfo->getName()) {
        echo $gameinfo->odds . "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: I was thinking it may be something similar to this...

$home=$gameinfo->OutcomeSet['Result']->Outcome['Odds'][0];
  $draw=$gameinfo->OutcomeSet['Result']->Outcome['Odds'][1];
  $away=$gameinfo->OutcomeSet['Result']->Outcome['Odds'][2];